# Make VbScript run as soon as you open get on computer after log off or restart

Tags: vbscript

Ok. So, I made this thing in vbs that says a little password when you log on. I am trying to make it say it as soon as you log on (if possible) because at the moment I have to click. I tried this script that someone suggested:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "notepad.exe c:\LOGON.vbs"
```

But that did not seem to work. So, thanks for your help!

Comment: still dident work i do not know why but it still did not show up

Comment: With your code shown above it open and edit the script c:\LOGON.vbs with notepad and not execute it ! show us the source code of this c:\LOGON.vbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these options might work for you...

1. Place the vbs file (or a shortcut) in your startup folder. E.g. C:\Documents and Settings\%UserName%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

or

2. Use Task Scheduler to define a task that is triggered 'when the computer starts' or 'when I log on' as described [here](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/create-automated-task-in-task-scheduler/). For a more programmatic approach there is [a C++ API for task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

or

3. Add the path to the vbs file to the registry depending on whether you want to run...

> for all users:
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.
>
> or a current user
>
> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: @Zoe Indeed. The original, official documentation seems to have been made scarce.  I've updated the answer with the most helpful alternatives I could find in a few minutes' search.  When I have more time I may expand the answer to incorporate the task scheduler how to.  Thanks for the heads up about the shortened links.